# Get <span> value from web page and authentication without asking user and password

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib, basic-authentication

I have this video surveillance software on Windows that has it's brower remote access with user/password authentication, on PC's IP. (I can also view from remote since I have a public IP).

I check the code in the browser UI and want to take these span values (`liveCameraCount` and `totalCameraCount`):

[image]

I use the lime code, that is work but reply with:

```
None
None
ON
```

While it should be

```
2
2
ON
```

(I've also try with a `time.sleep()` to let the page load but without success)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib2
import base64

url = "http://my.pc.ip.address:port"
username = "myuser"
password = "mypass"

handle = urllib2.Request(url)
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username,password))

data = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

cameras = soup.findAll('span')
for span in cameras:
    print span.string
```

I'm also trying to login automatically without that it ask every time:

```
Enter username [for my.pc.ip.address:port]:------
Enter password for username at [for my.pc.ip.address:port]:-----
```

EDIT 1:

OK. that's strange.
If I press F12 I can see the value inside  as the image posted, but if I press CRTL + U i see this code (without value). I don't understand:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
     <script>
    var isMobile =  navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry)/);
if(isMobile){
    window.location = '/mobile/';
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Sighthound</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sighthound-desktop.css" />

<style type="text/css">
    #liveTime{
        margin-left: 6px;
    }

    .views {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
</style>

  <!-- Favicons and touch icons -->
  <!-- For retina-display iPads -->
  <link href="/img/apple-touch-icon-xlarge.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-    precomposed" sizes="144x144" type="image/png"/>
  <!-- For retina-display iPhones -->
  <link href="/img/apple-touch-icon-large.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" type="image/png"/>
  <!-- For iPad 1 -->
  <link href="/img/apple-touch-icon-medium.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" type="image/png"/>
  <!-- For iPhone 3G, iPod Touch and Android -->
  <link href="/img/apple-touch-icon-small.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" type="image/png"/>
  <!-- For Nokia -->
  <link href="/img/apple-touch-icon-small.png" rel="shortcut icon"/>
  <!-- For everything else -->
  <link href="/img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"/>
  <link href="/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>  

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/handlebars-extras.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/xmlrpc.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sighthoundxmlrpc.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sighthound.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/purl.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/camera_display.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/all_cameras_control.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/common.js"></script>

     <div class="container">


        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" height="80" /></div><!-- End of Logo -->

            <div class="pageNav buttonBar">
                <a href="#" class="button active">Cameras</a>
                <a href="clips.html" class="button">Clips</a>
            </div><!-- End of Page Nav -->

            <div class="on-off buttonBar">
                <a id="allOffButton" href="#" class="button">Off</a>
                <a id="allOnButton" href="#" class="button">On</a>
            </div><!-- End of Buttons -->

            <div class="cameras">
                Cameras<br />
                <strong> <span id="liveCameraCount"></span> / <span id="totalCameraCount"></span> <span class="expressive">ON</span></strong>
            </div><!-- Camera -->

        </div><!-- End of Header -->



        <div class="content">

            <div class="contextMenu">

                <div id="liveTime" class="date"></div><!-- End of Date -->


                <!--<div class="fullscreen buttonBar">
                    <a href="" class="buttonIcon"><img src="img/iconFullscreen.png" width="18" /></a>
                </div>--><!-- End of Context Fullscreen -->


                <div class="views buttonBar">
                    <!--<a id="view1up" href="#" class="button viewButton"<img src="img/icon1upBlue.png" /></a>-->
                <a id="view2up" href="#" class="button viewButton"><img src="img/icon2upBlue.png" /></a>
                <a id="view3up" href="#" class="button viewButton"><img src="img/icon3upBlue.png" /></a>
                <a id="view4up" href="#" class="button active viewButton"><img src="img/icon4upWhite.png" /></a>
            </div><!-- End of Context Views -->


        </div><!-- End of Context -->

        <div id="cameraGrid"></div>

        <script id="cameraGridTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#everyNth cameras {(columns)}}}
                {{#if isModZeroNotFirst}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}

                {{#if isModZero}}
                    <div class="videos">
                {{/if}}

                <div class="video-{(columns)}up cameraVideo">

                    <a href="live.html?camera={{name}}&live={{live}}&cameraindex={{index}}">

                        <div class="videoImgContainer"
                            data-camera_index="{{index}}">
                            <!-- Image stream content is built by camera_display.js -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="cameraTitle">
                            <span>{{name}}<span>
                        </div>

                    </a>

                </div>

                {{#if isLast}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
            {{/everyNth}}

        </script>

    </div><!-- End of Content -->



</div><!-- End of Container -->

<script src="/js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the web page source?

Answer (score 0):

You could try swapping `string` for `text` as follows:

```
data = """<strong>
<span id="liveCameraCount">2</span>
" / "
<span id="totalCameraCount">2</span>
<span class="expressive">ON</span>
</strong>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for span in soup.findAll('span'):
    print span.text
```

This would display the following for your small example:

```
2
2
ON
```

For your full HTML, the first two `<span>`s are empty, so empty strings will be printed.